# Share twitter button not inline

Tags: php, wordpress

My twitter button to share a post isn't lining up with my Facebook button it's positioned way higher than my content and the Facebook button! Tried adding margin top etc but starts to cut the bottom of the button off!

Got the button from twitter.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please add your code?

Comment: I've literally got:

Comment: <div class="share"><\div> and inside I have the code twitter gives you for a share button that's it

Comment: Can you share a link to your button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using

tags? make sure those are aligned and then put the buttons inside there.

See below:

```html
<header id="header">
      <h1>Oops! Page couldn't be found</h1>
      <p>You may  Try  these links:</p>
      <nav>
       <ul>
       

      <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/user" class="icon fa-linkedin-square"><span class="label"></span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/user" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="icon fa-undo"><span class="label">Undo</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/user/" class="icon fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
      <!--onclick event for Email obstruction-->

      <li>

      <a href = "mailto:user" 

       onclick = "this.href=this.href

                     .replace(/AT/,'&#64;')

                     .replace(/DOT/,'&#46;')" 

                  class="icon fa-envelope"><span class="label">Email</span></a>

                 </li> 
                 
       </ul>
      </nav>
     </header>
    enter code here
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePDmv.png)

Comment: Tried that and they display online but twitter button still sits higher than the Facebook button

Comment: Yours worked in the end just had to float left! Thanks